# Two buttons inside the cell accepts the touch even when both the buttons touched simultaneously

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

For one of the cells inside tableview I have added two buttons. When I touch those buttons separately they performing their operations correctly. But the problem now is when I touch both the buttons simultaneously both accepts the touch and triggers their own target method. I don't want this to happen. Only one button should accept the touch at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I located solution for this by setting exclusiveTouch of the button to TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Use Exclusive Touch property:

```
self.button1.exclusiveTouch = true
```